# Handle auction time between users in different timezone

Tags: php, time

I have implemented my own script for auctions. But my problem is how to handle time.
Right now all auctions are based on UTC time, so whatever user's timezone is when he/she comes to site auction will start and end at the same time(UTC). I used date_default_timezone_set('UTC') to set default timezone throughout whole site.

But I guess that might be little bit confusing for users. Did anyone have similar problem and what could be the best solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a family website (family around the world).
All dates were stored with timestamp (which is UTC-timezone independent).
When a member created an account, he/she had to enter the country he/she was living it (as the PHP timezone guess is not reliable).
From that, I stored the name of the timezone of his /her country (https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).
When the member logs in, I PHP-set the timezone to his/her country to display dates with his/her timezone.